# Paypal chained payment gives error to all my users in production environment

Tags: paypal, payment, chained

I've an iOS application that needs to let the users sell their products using paypal. With chained payment I send to me the 10% of the price of the object. I used this paypal API that in sandbox environment works well:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/

In production environment, when users try to pay an object paypal site return to them the following error "Your payment can’t be completed. Please return to the participating website and try again."

I've tried to follow the steps that you can see in this link http://support.audiogon.com/customer/portal/articles/1507399-paypal-your-payment-cannot-be-completed- without success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you get an app ID approved for the production servers, and does it include all of the calls you're actually making?  Sometimes people get approved, but they didn't specify everything they're actually doing, so then when you go live you find out PayPal never approved/enabled a particular feature you're working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that all merchant account sellers have not checked "Initiate payments from the Pay Anyone subtab of the Send Money tab"?

Comment: You're right! I've checked that users has not checked "Initiate payments from the Pay Anyone subtab of the Send Money tab" but I didn't check if the merchant account that there is in the chained payment had the some option unchecked. Now everything works well, thank you!